# Negative balance after sendfrom bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind

Any one can explain me why I get a negative balance after execute a sendfrom ?

"sendfrom myaccount btcaddress amount"
and right after
"getbalance myaccount" return  a negative balance

I don't really understand why the balance is negative ...

After 1confirmation, the balance come back to his real value.

Answer (score 1):

Read this issue: 
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/2079

As  gavinandresen commented December 06, 2012

> Yes, that is a 'WONTFIX'.
>
> A sendall account  command that took the account to exactly
>   zero might be a good solution, although you can still run into edge
>   cases like "what if the account contains 0.000001 BTC" (fee to sendall
>   might be greater than that).