# Manage multiple users wallets for web wallet service

Tags: wallet, bitcoind, transaction-fees, raw-transaction, bitcoin-cli

[This](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/43532/86150) already summaries the issue I'm currently trying to figure out to calculate the transaction fee to prevent negative balance.

(testnet) I tried using `createrawtransaction` [answered](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/43601/86150).
When I tried to send all balance to an address, the `txid` was created successfully using `createrawtransaction` but when I ran the `fundrawtranaction` on that `txid` it showed

```
error code: -4
error message:
Insufficient funds
```

<s>The goal is to calculate transaction fee before hand to check either sufficient balance is available of an account using `sendfrom`</s>

To manage multiple users to isolate users' balances as [this](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2904484.0).

**EDIT1:**

If using `estimatesmartfee` it is showing the fee:

```
bitcoin-cli -testnet estimatesmartfee 6
{
  "feerate": 0.00501921,
  "blocks": 6
}
```

When calling `sendfrom` for total balance transfer:

```
bitcoin-cli -testnet sendfrom <account> <address> <amount>
error code: -4
error message:
Error: This transaction requires a transaction fee of at least 0.00067257
```

Is there a way to get `0.00067257` the fee part before send the transaction amount and set it so that account balance won't go negative for multi accounts wallet.

**Edit 2:**

I found out that accounts are [deprecated](https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/bitcoin.org/issues/1287).

And multi wallet creation/load/unload on runtime is underway to [0.17.0](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/13058)

So what would be the best approach to handle multiple users bitcoins in isolation on a full node to prevent negative balance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `estimatesmartfee 6` to calculate suggested BTC/kB fee aiming confirmation in six blocks. Then you can do `fundrawtransaction <tx> "{feeRate: 0.000something}"` to add inputs with the specified fee. This way, you'll have more control over the fees.